# Should I grind until last minute for a story palace, or clear it as soon as I can?

Tags: persona-5

I'm in the first palace, and I get 2 weeks to beat it.

I'm close to clearing it on Friday of the first week, but IDK if I should push now to clear it or grind the mobs for levels/money before clearing it on the eleventh hour.

The story so far seems to hint at the fact that when I clear it, the palace would be gone and so the mobs in it would, I guess, not be accessible anymore.

So in most cases, is it preferable to clear the story palace as soon as possible, or is it better to wait, grind what you can before clearing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you’re adequately leveled to take on the palace ruler, you should be fine. There’s no need to grind for future palaces in the current palace. Even though the palace disappears once you’ve cleared it, there will always be Mementos if you feel so inclined to grind.

Near the end of the game, it’s extremely easy to level your party beyond what is necessary for the final boss by farming the Reaper, as I’ve described in my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/307360/162442).

Comment: Follow up question: Are chests that are left unopened lost? You can't get them in any way afterwards?

Comment: @Fredy31 yes, but I don’t recall there being anything in them that you can’t just get somewhere else